# How to install webkitgtk-6.0 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, dependencies

I am trying to install [planify](https://github.com/alainm23/planify) on Ubuntu 22.04.

**src/meson.build** has dependency

```
dependency('webkitgtk-6.0')
```

Could anyone please tell me, where to get this package and how I can install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-6.0-4
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-6.0-dev
```

Comment: I executed: `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-6.0-4`
But when I: `meson build --prefix=/usr`, it still tells me: `Dependency "webkitgtk-6.0" not found`.

By the way, I have found folder **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkitgtk-6.0**: (`injected-bundle/libwebkitgtkinjecteddbundle.so`, `*MiniBrowser`, `*WebKitNetworkProcess`, `*WebKitWebProcess`). 
I tried to write to **.bashrc**: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkitgtk-6.0`. But it still tells me the same.

What else can I do?

Comment: @fedor.khandarov  Updated my answer

Comment: Yes! It helps! Thank you!